# How to design logging data from multiple sources

Tags: python, logging

I have a multiple modules running that I want to retrieve data from and store it via a centralised logger. Modules are written in either C or Python. The logger is written in Python. The data is in JSON object sent through POST request to the server.

I am not sure if I should add functionality to each module to report data to logger, or if the logger should ask to retrieve that information itself. To make it simple for the example, lets say I have two modules, one is monitoring data and needs to continuously report a value every second. Second module would report data based on events. When an event occurs it needs to be logged. So it would log a change in value that could happen at any time.

I am asking because I don't want to introduce dependencies for each module on the logger. An alternative would be another small piece of code that retrieves values from the first module all the time and monitors if there's a change in value in the second module. It then passes that data to logger when needed.

Data from the first module would look like that, in the format (Time stamp, value):

```
[(0,100), (1,110), (2,120), (3, 100)]
```

And from the second one:

```
[(0,0), (10, 5), (12, 7), (20, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good questions which many people get wrong. Here are a couple of things to consider:

1. You want to minimize the changes to the modules you develop when you want to change log format etc'
2. Application performance should not be affected by a problem in the logging mechanism
3. Logging infrastructure can sustain bursts of logs

There are a couple of ways to go about it:
1. Run a simple agent like rsyslog, nxlog or logstash on each machine that generates events. Theses agents know how to get JSON or other formats and ship them efficiently to a central logger. It will reduce the integration burden and would minimize performance impact

2. Write an appender that does a simple post of each Log's JSON to your central logger. It does require tighter integration and you have the burden of doing it efficiently but it can be the best way.

You can look at http://Logz.io repository on Github (https://github.com/logzio) there are some open source appenders you can use (for #2).

Good luck.